# How to format a pandas dataframe for use with pandas-highcharts within Django

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I'm trying to use pandas-highcharts within a Django project; I'm able to produce the graph, but the data is not plotted, so I'm guessing my pandas dataframe is not formatted correctly, or maybe I'm not using the right method to render the template.

The result:
[image: resulting highchart graph]

My dataframe:

```
                           Entrée d'eau - Archimède - 0013A2004166CFCD
timestamp                                                             
2016-12-23 00:05:18+00:00                                         29.0
2016-12-23 00:05:27+00:00                                         29.0
2016-12-23 00:05:37+00:00                                         29.0
2016-12-23 00:05:47+00:00                                         29.0
2016-12-23 00:05:58+00:00                                         29.0
```

My view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from data.models import Value
import pandas as pd
from pandas_highcharts.core import serialize

# [...]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    Value.objects.filter(device=a).values("timestamp", "leak_value"))

df.dropna(inplace=True)  # not sure about this
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df = df.truncate(
    before=pd.to_datetime(request.POST.get("start")),
    after=pd.to_datetime(request.POST.get("stop")))
df = df.rename(
    index=str,
    columns={"leak_value": "{} - {} - {}".format(
        Room.objects.filter(unit=unit_sel).get(device=a),
        Device.objects.get(address=a).devicetype,
        a)})

print(df.head())  # DEBUG

chart = serialize(
    df=df,
    render_to='Leak Values',
    title="Leak Values",
    output_type='json')

return render(request, "leak_chart.html", context={"chart": chart})
```

My template (I include jquery and highcharts in base.html):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}

    {% load staticfiles %}

    <div id="Leak Values"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Highcharts.Chart({{chart|safe}});
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

The page source:
https://pastebin.com/EkJYQPLQ

By the way I haven't found a tag for pandas-highcharts and I don't think I have the privileges to create it.  I'm using pandas-highcharts 0.5.2

EDIT: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848091/highcharts-and-php-json-encode-data-from-mysql-no-data-on-chart) seems related but I'm unable to apply the answer to my specific situation.

Comment: Can you check what's the format is being passed to leak_chart.html of chart..?? Is it even a JSON format..??

Comment: The series should look like this: `series: [{
 name: 'Jane',
 data: [1, 0, 4]
}, {
 name: 'John',
 data: [5, 7, 3]
}]`  This is what I extracted from the page source after generating the graph: `"series": [{
 "data": [
  ["2016-12-23 00:05:18+00:00", 29.0],
  ["2016-12-23 00:05:27+00:00", 29.0],
  ["2016-12-23 19:11:34+00:00", 29.0]
 ],
 "yAxis": 0,
 "name": "Entr\u00e9e d'eau - Archim\u00e8de - 0013A2004166CFCD"
}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to change was to add `use_index=False`, now my data is shown:

```
chart = serialize(
            df=final_df,
            render_to='Leak Values',
            title="Leak Values",
            use_index=False,
            output_type='json')
```

However the timestamps are not shown, so I guess I'll have to make pandas-highcharts recognize them as datetime, as @Kamil Kulig suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Categories in Highcharts work as the values for axis' labels. If you want to assign a point's coordinate (x, y or z) to a category you should use a category index from `categories` array:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['cat1', 'cat2']
}

series: [{
  data: [
    [0 /*refers to the 'cat1' category */, someValue], 
    [1,/*refers to the 'cat1' category */, someValue]
  ]
}]
```

I think that in this example the better approach is to use `datetime` type of the x axis (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type) and convert your x values to timestamps. In this case there's no need to use categories at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it lead me to find precisely how to fix my code to use pandas-highcharts.